# Is it possible to get compiled scoped css out of svelte component?

Tags: svelte, svelte-component

Is it possible to get compiled scoped css string out of svelte component?
For example by clicking on the button

Something like this

```
<script>
    function getCss() {
        // get compiled scoped css string of this component
    }
</script>

<button on:click={getCss}>Get css</button>

<style>
    button {
        padding: 5px 10px;
        border: none;
        background-color: green;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Yes, it is most likely possible as this is done by the svelte compiler itself.  Basically, you'll have to compile the component and capture the produced CSS as data.  How, exactly?  Don't ask me. :-)  I recommend you join Svelte's Discord server and ask there.